# What is the difference between M2Crypto's set_client_CA_list_from_file() and load_verify_info() and when would you use each?

Tags: python, m2crypto

The [M2Crypto library](http://chandlerproject.org/bin/view/Projects/MeTooCrypto) has a few CA-related functions on its [SSL.Context object](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.SSL.Context'.Context-class.html), but the documentation is very unclear as to when you would use certain functions and why.  In fact, the docs for almost all of them are, "Load CA certs into the context," so it seems possible that they all do the same thing.

There are [several](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2008/10/14/ssl-in-python-26/) [examples](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~danken/SecureXMLRPCServer.py) that use both `set_client_CA_list_from_file()` and `load_verify_info()`, but there are also other similar functions like `load_client_ca()` and `load_verify_locations()`.

I am writing both client and server pieces.  What functions should I use and why?  What specifically do they do?

**Edit:**

Looking through the code I see:

```
# Deprecated.
load_client_CA = load_client_ca = set_client_CA_list_from_file
```

and

```
# Deprecated.
load_verify_info = load_verify_locations
```

So that helps a little.  This brings us down to two functions: `set_client_CA_list_from_file()` and `load_verify_locations()`.  But I still can't quite tell the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server requires the client to present a certificate, it can restrict who are the valid issuers of the client certificates by specifying the issuers calling [**set_client_CA_list_from_file**](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.SSL.Connection%27.Connection-class.html#set_client_CA_list_from_file). This is actually pretty rare.

The client specifies who are the valid server certificate issuers by calling [**load_verify_locations**](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.SSL.Context%27.Context-class.html#load_verify_locations). Almost all clients should do this.

Both client and server can call [**load_cert**](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.SSL.Context%27.Context-class.html#load_cert) to set their own certificate. Servers should almost always do this. Clients should probably do this only if the server requires the client to present a certificate.

I recommend you pick a copy of **Network Security with OpenSSL** by John Viega, Matt Messier and Pravir Chandra, ISBN 059600270X, which should clarify these issues in more detail.